# How do I minimize this Boolean expression?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

How do I minimize the following expression $$W'\cdot X'+ X'\cdot Y' + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z$$

where $\cdot$ stands for Logical AND, $'$ stands for Negation and $+$ stands for Logical OR.

Comment: by minimizing you mean finding a logically equivalent "shortest" possible expression?

Comment: Draw a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to find a minimum set of terms.

Comment: Yes, you may also call it a valid shortest possible expression.

Comment: +Axel, I'm not familiar with K-maps (maybe the professor will talk about it in the next lecture), Is there a way to minimize it other than the k-map?

Comment: @Zaraki this is already minimized. It has a minimal canonical form as sum of products. K-map won't help. If you don't mind the form to be canonical, you can save an AND by factorying out $W'$ from the first and third terms.

Comment: @trying Actually, it can be simplified more; see my Answer... a K-map should show that too.

Comment: @Bram28 great +1. Yes, K-map shows it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$W'\cdot X'+ X'\cdot Y' + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z = \text{ (Adjacency)}$$

$$W'\cdot X' \cdot Y + W'\cdot X' \cdot Y' + X'\cdot Y' + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z = \text{ (Adjacency)}$$

$$W'\cdot X' \cdot Y \cdot Z + W'\cdot X' \cdot Y \cdot Z' + W'\cdot X' \cdot Y' \cdot Z + X'\cdot Y' + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z = \text{ (Absorption x 3)}$$

$$X'\cdot Y' + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z $$

Just to be clear, in the last step:

$X' \cdot Y'$ absorbs $W'\cdot X' \cdot Y'$

$W'\cdot Z'$ absorbs $W'\cdot X' \cdot Y \cdot Z'$

$Y \cdot Z$ absorbs $W'\cdot X' \cdot Y \cdot Z$

You can also use the [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem):

$$P \cdot Q + Q' \cdot R + P \cdot R = P \cdot Q + Q' \cdot R$$

Applied to your statement:

$$W'\cdot X'+ X'\cdot Y' + \color{green}{W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z} = \text{ (Consensus)}$$

$$\color{green}{W'\cdot X'+ X'\cdot Y'} + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z + \color{green}{W' \cdot Y}= \text{ (Consensus)}$$

$$X'\cdot Y' + \color{green}{W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z + W' \cdot Y}= \text{ (Consensus)}$$

$$X'\cdot Y' + W'\cdot Z' + Y \cdot Z$$